# Argument parsing python using ArgParse

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, argparse

I am creating a python script and for parsing the arguments I would need this:
the script will accept three parameters, only one always mandatory, the second one will only be mandatory depending on certain values of the first one and the third one may or may not appear.
This is my try:

```
class pathAction(argparse.Action):
folder = {'remote':'/path1', 'projects':'/path2'}
def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option = None):
    args.path = values
    print "ferw %s " % args.component
    if args.component=='hos' or args.component=='hcr':
        print "rte %s" % args.path
        if args.path and pathAction.folder.get(args.path):
            args.path = pathAction.folder[args.path]
        else:
            parser.error("You must enter the folder you want to clean: available choices[remote, projects]")   

def main():
try:
    # Arguments parsing
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""This script will clean the old component files.""")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--component",  help="component to clean",  type=lowerit, choices=["hos", "hcr", "mdw", "gui"], required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",       help="path to clean", action = pathAction, choices = ["remote", "projects"])
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--delete",     help="parameter for deleting the files from the filesystem", nargs='*', default=True)


    args = parser.parse_args()
```

if works well except one case: if i have -c  it should complain because there is no -p however it does not
Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: You're looking for http://bugs.python.org/issue11588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your special `action` will be used only if there is a `-p` argument.  If you just give it a `-c` the cross check is never used.

Generally checking for interactions after `parse_args` (as `Gohn67` suggested) is more reliable, and simpler than with custom actions.

What happens if your commandline was `'-p remote -c ...'`?  `pathAction` would be called before the `-c` value is parsed and set.  Is that what you want?  Your special action only works if `-p` is given, and is the last argument.

---

Another option is to make 'component' a subparser positional.  By default positionals are required.  `path` and `delete` can be added to those subparsers that need them.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""This script will clean the old component files.""")
p1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
p1.add_argument("path", help="path to clean", choices = ["remote", "projects"])
p2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
p2.add_argument("-d", "--delete", help="parameter for deleting the files from the filesystem", nargs='*', default=True)
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='component',description="component to clean")
sp.add_parser('hos', parents=[p1,p2])
sp.add_parser('hcr', parents=[p1,p2])
sp.add_parser('mdw', parents=[p2])
sp.add_parser('gui', parents=[p2])
print parser.parse_args()
```

sample use:

```
1848:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack21625446.py hos remote -d 1 2 3
Namespace(component='hos', delete=['1', '2', '3'], path='remote')
```

I used `parents` to simplify adding arguments to multiple subparsers.  I made `path` a positional, since it is required (for 2 of the subparsers).  In those cases `--path` just makes the user type more.  With `nargs='*'`, `--delete` has to belong to the subparsers so it can occur last.  If it's `nargs` was fixed (`None` or number) it could be an argument of `parser`.

Comment: this solution seems so good for my purpose. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add some custom validation like this:

```
if args.component and not args.path:
    parser.error('Your error message!')
```

Comment: no because args.path would depend on CERTAIN values of args.component, actually args.component should be always entered.. any clue??